# How to check if an image region contains text or not?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to implement a license plate detection algorithm, so far I have narrowed it down to a few interest regions:

[image]

My next step would be to classify each interest region and ignore the false regions. I was thinking maybe I can check each region for character. If the region contains some characters, then it is a plate, otherwise, it's a false region. How would I go about checking for characters?

Another approach I can think of is to use PCA to determine if a region contains plate, but I have no idea how to do it in OpenCV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text detection is not an easy task at all. It may be harder than the whole plate detection you are building. I can suggest you a simple tricky approach:

1. Find contours inside each region.
2. Find bounding rectangle around each contour.
3. delete very small or very larg rectangle.
4. Check weather these contours are represent a straight line. The region with contours that are arranged in linear way is the plate.

Answer (score 3):

There is a technique called MSER (Maximally stable extremal regions). It detects connected blobs of similar color (which individual letters usually are). Then you classify these blobs to tell if they are letters or not. Then it's called CSER.

See [OpenCV doc](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/erfilter.html), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximally_stable_extremal_regions)

Also there is a [Quasi-Linear version of the algorithm](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-88688-4_14), if you feel like implementing it yourself.